# How can I find the aspect ratios of 2 "rectangles" on the same plane in a 3d image?

Tags: opencv, homography

[Based on this paper](http://www1.icsi.berkeley.edu/~stellayu/publication/doc/2008roomPOCV.pdf)

On page 4 the authors indicate they will rectify these 2 quadrilaterals by computing a homography, using `TWO DEFINING LINES` to determine the aspect ratio.

I understand the transform using the homography should be quite simple if I know the dimensions of the target rectangle(s).

What I want to know is, what `TWO DEFNINING LINES` are they referring to?

I need to compare the overlap and areas of the two rectangles, so they must be on the same scale.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

How to get the two defining lines is described in sections 2.2 and 2.3 on page 3.
It seems to be "Lines that are next to each other but point in different directions
are likely to come from the same planar surface". You need to go through the equations for A||, A_ and A_|_ , they closely relate to finding the defining lines  - to fully understand this I think you will have to look at Stella Yu's paper (ref 24)

Comment: Ok, perhaps I'm making too much of it. I understand what the lines are that define the quadrilateral. Unfortunately the further back in the image you go (toward infinity) the more weight must be given to length of the segments. I was looking to calculate that weight somehow to get the correct dimensions of the rectangle represented by this quadrilateral. But if all they're doing is taking two sides and putting them at a right angle, then accuracy isn't important. Thank you.